# Visual Studio and .DLL Version Number

Tags: visual-studio, dll

I am trying to figure out which SAPI version I have installed on my Win XP Pro laptop.

I am adding sapi.dll to my project:
Project > Add Reference > COM:
Microsoft Speech Object Library 5.0   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Speech\sapi.dll

If I open Windows Explorer and navigate to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Speech\sapi.dll, it shows the version number as 5.1.4111.0

The interop file that is created by the Visual Studio (Interop.SpeechLib.dll) shows version number as 5.0.0.0

If I go to Project > Add Reference > Browse and manually browse for the dll, it makes no difference. While the physical dll shows version 5.1.4111.0, everything in Visual Studio turns into version 5.0.0.0

Why the discrepancy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the type library version doesn't have anything to do with the file version.  The library version describes the *declared* interface of the API.  When a breaking change is made that requires programs to be recompiled then the library version is incremented.

The file version is an *implementation* detail.  There were probably multiple revisions of it on XP, say for different service packs or security patches.  "5.1" here means the *Windows* version number.  4.0 = Windows NT,  5.0 = Windows 2000, 5.1 = XP, 6.0 = Vista, 6.1 = Windows 7.  A change in the file version doesn't require your program to be recompiled.  You only care about the library version.

Comment: Thanks.

I am not sure what a "breaking change" is. I have tinkered with the program making some minor changes and recompiling it. However the interop library (Interop.SpeechLib.dll) is still version number 5.0.0.0 and is dated from the time I first created the reference.

If the interop library number is completely different from the DLL version number, why did the VS start it with 5.0.0.0? Why not 1.0.0.0? 
Excuse my newbie questions. DLLs and versioning are not my strong suits.

Comment: The interop assembly version number is the same as the COM type library version number.  That type library is embedded in sapi.dll as a resource.  That probably doesn't mean much if you don't know enough about COM.  The best thing to do here is to stop worrying about it, there's nothing wrong.

Comment: Thanks, it makes much more sense now.
So does it mean that I have SAPI 5.1 installed (as per DLL version)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I would just like to know in general if I should take the DLL version number as the API version number.

Comment: OK, I think I got it now.
The COM type library embedded in the sapi.dll file is version 5.0.0.0 and that means that SAPI is version 5.0. Is this correct?